# Need a troubleshooting guide for Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench

I am having numerous issues in Workbench and am looking for a useful trouble-shooting guide.

- I can open the individual *.m and *.nb files.
- Opening projects is completely hit or miss. There is no error message that appears if the project does not open.
- The Outline is available when projects are initially created. If the project does open in Workbench, the outline is unavailable - even after a refresh or re-start.
- Project files and notebooks do successfully load in Mathematica 11.3.
- The Eclipse IDE often drops location of the Mathematica EXE.
- I am on my third complete uninstall and re-install of the Eclipse IDE and the Workbench add-in.
- I have re-created the project twice and the same issues simply continue.
- I use Visual Studio, Mathematica and SystemModeler on the same box and encounter no such similar issues with these products. There are also no known hardware issues.

Is this a common Workbench scenario with a known solution? Is a troubleshooting guide available for the Eclipse Workbench plug-in?

I have seen the posts for third-party alternatives and will explore these.